# Facebook Photo Picker Controller for iOS (similar to the Places Picker controller)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, facebook-ios-sdk

I was wondering if there is any simple Facebook Photo Picker controller for iOS that would show facebook albuns and their photos and let the user pick photos from them. Something similar to Places Picker UI component found in the iOS Facebook SDK (FBPlacePickerViewController) or to iOS UIImagePickerController but for choosing photos from facebook albuns.

I've seen many iPhone apps that have this kind of functionality and I thought there was something already done in the Facebook SDK but I was wrong. I also wasn't able to find any simple controller to do the it.

I've found this two - Photopickerplus and GrabKit - that let user choose from many sources but wanted something more simple that this, just for facebook, and more easy to integrate in my app.

Also found this one, that looked just like what I needed, but it uses Three20 that has no support anymore and is not easy to integrate in the app:
https://github.com/GrioSF/FacebookPhotoBrowser

Finally found this extension to the iOS UIImagePickerController that may be the best option but would like to know if there is already something more suited for what I need:
https://github.com/jeena/JPImagePickerController

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SO is more about solving actual issues you are facing, not offering opinions.

Comment: NO, I would like to know if there is controller more suited for what I need than the options I found. It's a very common feature so I might be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

I needed it for my own project. So i created it. I didn't know about Option2 so i created mine. U can try both. If u encounters any error in my project then please tell me. I've tested but i removed some properties that was only specific for my project.

> **OPTION 1: (Made by me)**

Here's the link.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3PZzP2RSGt4YmtqWVpKRDVvMTA/edit?usp=sharing

Add **two folders** in your project &

**Use below code**

```
FacebookAlbumPicker *objFBImagePicker = [[FacebookAlbumPicker alloc] initWithNibName:@"FacebookAlbumPicker" bundle:nil];
objFBImagePicker.delegate = self;

UINavigationController *objNavBarForFacebook = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:objFBImagePicker];
[self presentController:objNavBarForFacebook animated:YES];
```

**And Implement `FBImagePickerDelegate` delegate with delegate method `imagePickingFinishedWithImage:` (which is required).**

> **OPTION 2: (Found on Cocoacontrols.com)**

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/facebook-photo-picker

**EDIT:**

**Update link with working demo (As of 21 March 2014 with Facebook SDK 3.13)**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3PZzP2RSGt4b0VzOW42dWtzbjQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm trying using it but I get the error
"FacebookAlbumCell.h' not found and
"BaseViewController.h" not found. I cannot find this file in the archive.

Comment: Btw, any update relative to components like these? I'm having serious troubles finding anything recent.

Comment: Ok, in the meanwhile, do you know if there is any other component I can test for comparison purposes? GrabKit was not working for me and the others reported in these question contained legacy code with low compatibility.

Comment: @Claus, check updated link, Its working demo. I've tested it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Cool, I will test it soon and let you know!

Comment: Trying the code right now. Apparently there is a missing file in the archive. 

FacebookAlbumCell.h

Comment: I'll check it later.. Right now you can replace it with your own custom cell or just use default cell...

Comment: btw also ""BaseViewController.h" is missing

Comment: @Claus,, Did you download files using updated link? This one.. I ran this demo & its working.. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3PZzP2RSGt4b0VzOW42dWtzbjQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Trying to integrate it right now, I will let you know soon. Thanks.

Comment: Ok,it's running but I get this error: "FBSession: a permission request for publish or manage permissions contains unexpected read permissions" have you ever seen it? The album table is then empty

Comment: Do u get something else in log??

Comment: Did you run on device or simulator? I'm running on the simulator.

Comment: Ok, I get LOGIN SUCCESS (I know for sure the session is active), but after that log message I get an empty dataset

Comment: Finally it's working!!! As I used Parse for login with Facebook I wasn't setting the permission for getting the photos at the very beginning of the login session. Adding it made the trick. 
You did a great job, I would strongly suggest to create a GitHub repository and to publish this component as I'm sure a lot of people will appreciate it!

Comment: I will for sure and will update link here too.. @Claus