# Xcode Adding 3rd Party Code To My Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Sorry, I'm an Obj-c noob so I'm probably just missing something simple...

I'm trying to add the code in this question to my project. I want to have a simple facebook photo chooser. What does he mean when he says, "And Implement FBImagePickerDelegate delegate with delegate method imagePickingFinishedWithImage: (which is required)."?

[Facebook Photo Picker Controller for iOS (similar to the Places Picker controller)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21049234/facebook-photo-picker-controller-for-ios-similar-to-the-places-picker-controlle/21901534#21901534)

I've added the files to my project but am getting some errors. For one, it doesn't understand FBSession, which was easy to fix by importing the facebook SDK, then however I get another error.

No visible @interface for UIImageView declares the selector 'setImageWithUrl' on this line...

```
 [objCell.imgAlbumCoverPhoto setImageWithURL:urlPhoto];
```

Comment: Post your code.  Can't help if we don't know what you've written.

Comment: Please don't get into using third party libraries in your code. As you said, you are newbie at iOS development. I suggest building up your basics first. You should know how to fix errors like those before going into using third party libraries.

Comment: Can someone explain what he meant with the "and implement..."? That would be enough, I think.

Comment: Implement a delegate means you add it to your interface for example 
`@interface yourViewController  :UIViewController<FBImagePickerDelegate>`

Comment: You need to implement a class that conforms to the FBImagePickerDelegate protocol, and on that object implement the method imagePickingFinishedWithImage:. If you're not familiar with the concept of delegation, see this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/Delegation.html

Comment: I highly suggest learning how to use CocoaPods now. It makes using 3rd party libraries so much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

objCell.imgAlbumCoverPhoto is that a subclass of UIImageView? because UIImageView have no method called setImageWithURL by default. Then you probably havn't imported the headerfile  for that class correctly.